# Appending time taken to execute test into end-user friendly .xls/.csv file

Tags: java, excel, csv, selenium, testng

Right now, we successfully/accurately report test IDs, Descriptions, Expected Results, and Pass/Fail values. I'd like to add the values that I can see at the end of running testng.xml (time taken to execute and finish test) and append them to my file.

Is there a way to record the time taken of TestNG tests and output them into Excel/CSV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test run times are part of the XML report: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#logging-xml-reports

You can parse the file and extract the data you need.